# Blender vertex mapping code

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

This below is my code that is trying to put empties over the verts on the selected mesh but for some reason every time I run the code blender just crashes.
I am testing the code on the basic cube.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
i = 0
c = 7
obj = context.active_object

while not i == c:
    v = obj.data.vertices[i]
    co_final = obj.matrix_world @ v.co
    obj_empty = bpy.data.objects.new("Point", None)
    context.collection.objects.link(obj_empty)
    obj_empty.location = co_final
    i + 1
```

Comment: It shouldn't crash; it loops forever. `i + 1` should be `i += 1`. But it'd be better to use `for v in obj.data.vertices: ...`.

Comment: .... looping forever while adding an object will ultimately hang or crash blender.  Can kill a script by pressing Ctrl-C over the system console. (_IMO always have system console open when writing scripts_).  As above adds empties with global coords Can also make the object the empty's parent `obj_empty.parent = obj` and then set `obj_empty.location = v.co`    to give empties coords matching the underlying verts.